# Loop through Dates in database and calculate days remaining to the date on each row

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, date, calculation

I am trying to figure out how to loop through the database and calculate the remaining days untill the individual date per row.

Date format 6/15/2017 m/d/y but printed it shows y/m/d as show later in the question. (Currently sitting as varchar in the DB, this will be changed to DATE)

Stack info: Xampp 5.6.30 (Apache + MariaDB + PHP + Perl) I don't use Perl.

I have gotten as far as getting an array with all the dates.

This is the code that gets the array:
$dates = array();

```
$Kal_get = "SELECT Next_Kal FROM Maaleinstrumenter_final";
$Result = mysqli_query($conn, $Kal_get);
WHILE ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result))
```

Furthermore i have succeeded in calculating 1 row with (The date is not the right one and should be filled with data from $Row)

```
$date = strtotime("December 3, 2009");
$remaining = $date - time();  
WHILE($day = floor($remaining / 86400));
Echo $day;
```

The 2 scripts are not joined together as i tried to make a variable that would loop the calculation but it looped endlessly. This might be fixable by nesting it in an if statement.

How would i proceed as to join the 2 scripts and get 300+ results and devide them into 3 groups (more than a month, less than a month and less than 10 days)

Things that i have observed:
The wile loop that assembles the array somehow shows up as 360+ arrays as showed here with a 2 row var_dump on $Row and not as 1 array like `$x['1'], $x['2']` and so on:

```
array(1) { ["Next_Kal"]=> string(10) "1993-12-12" } 
array(1) { ["Next_Kal"]=> string(10) "0000-00-00" }
```

I goofed earlier on and reset all the data on the dates and i changed the first row to show an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept tinkering since it wouldn't fit in perfectly, this is what i ended up with as a successful script for calculating dates remaining on 366 rows.

```
$Kal_get = "SELECT Bunny_No, Next_Kal, DATEDIFF(NOW(), Next_Kal) FROM Maaleinstrumenter_final";
$Result = mysqli_query($conn, $Kal_get);
$a = 30;
$b = 10;
$moreThan2Months = array();
$lessThan1Month = array();
$lessThan10Days = array();

while($Row = mysqli_fetch_array($Result))
{
$absoluteDays = abs($Row['DATEDIFF(NOW(), Next_Kal)']);
if($absoluteDays > $a) {$moreThan2Months[] = ($Row['DATEDIFF(NOW(), Next_Kal)']);}
elseif($absoluteDays < $a && $absoluteDays >$b) {$lessThan1Month[] = $Row['DATEDIFF(NOW(), Next_Kal)'];}
elseif($absoluteDays < $b) {$lessThan10Days[] = $Row['DATEDIFF(NOW(), Next_Kal)'];}}
echo count(array_filter($lessThan1Month));
?>
```

It is successfully calculating the dates and put them into `$absoluteDays` and split them into 3 arrays based on the `If/Ifelse` statements and then later counted and filtered to only show non-NULL elements inside the array, making it able to count dynamically.
THANKS FOR ALL THE HELP I RECIEVED ON THIS QUESTION IT'S GREATLY APPRICIATED!! <3

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql's DATEDIFF function:

```
SELECT Next_Kal, DATEDIFF(NOW(), Next_Kal) as Days_Remaining
FROM Maaleinstrumenter_final
```

Comment: So that will create an array looking like $x['1'] filled with all of the calculations?

Comment: Assuming you are using while($x=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) as your loop, then yes $x['0'] will contain the date stored in your database, and $x['1'] will contain the number of days from now until the date specific in $x['0'] .

Comment: I just tried it out, the var_dump shows that the calculation of days is correct+1 which is fine, but it shows up as "-75" which i can live with since it doesn't matter to me as long as there is the right amount of days :-)

How would i loop it and split the array into 3 arrays depending on how many days left?

Comment: Can you show me an example of expected results based on sample database data?

Comment: I will try my best. 
Let's say i run the script you gave me, it output 360+ rows in the array.
100 of them as 2+ months (Turn green in the echo'd table)
100 are less than a month (Turn yellow in the echo'd table)
160 are less than 10 days (Turn red in the echo'd table)

The way i think it could be achieved is by adding `If`` and `Ifelse` and `Ifelse` to the loop like:
`If(date_Remaining > 30){Code that puts that row into array 1 (Green)}`
`Ifelse(date_Remaining <=30){Code that puts that row into array 2 (Yellow)`
`Ifelse(date_Reamining < 10){Code that put that row into array 3 (Red)}`

Comment: Is this helping? It was too long to format and make it look nice :-)

Comment: You will need at separate during the loop. Example: `$moreThan2Months = array();
$lessThan1Month = array();
$lessThan10Days = array();
while($x = mysqli_fetch_array($Result)) {
    $absoluteDays = abs($x[1]);
    // More than 2 months
    if($absoluteDays > 60) {
        $moreThan2Months[] = $x[0];
    }
    // Less than 1 month
    if($absoluteDays < 30) {
        $lessThan1Month[] = $x[0];
    }
    // Less than 10 days
    if($absoluteDays < 10) {
        $lessThan10Days[] = $x[0];
    }
}

var_dump($moreThan2Months,$lessThan1Month,$lessThan10Days);`

Comment: I haven't tested yet, but it looks just just what i need looking through the code, and i can hostely say that is is the most accurate help anyone has ever given me on this site ^^ <3

Comment: I actually think it works just as it should, but after running the script and var_dumping on $Row it looks like `{$absoluteDays = abs($Row[1]);` is obsolete, could you elaborate it's function?

Comment: Why 3 arrays, when you can sort rows by "days" ?

Comment: @Marcodor i have 2 windows that echo the number of rows with either < 30 days or <10 days. And the 3 arrays will also be used to specify which rows in the echo'd table that should change color dynamically

Comment: @KevinHR i set it up like this:

`$Kal_get = "SELECT Next_Kal,Trescal_No, DATEDIFF(NOW(), Next_Kal) as Days_Remaining FROM Maaleinstrumenter_final";
$Result = mysqli_query($conn, $Kal_get);
$moreThan2Months = array();
$lessThan1Month = array();
$lessThan10Days = array();
  
  
 
 while ($Row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($Result))
 {$absoluteDays = abs($Row['Next_Kal']); 
 if($absoluteDays > 30) { $moreThan2Months[] = $Row['Next_Kal']; }
 if($absoluteDays < 30) { $lessThan1Month[] = $Row['Next_Kal']; }
 if($absoluteDays < 10) { $lessThan10Days[] = $Row['Next_Kal']; }  `

Comment: I suck at getting the formats right when pasting code snippets -.-... Anyways when i run this and use a`var_dump`  on`$moreThan2Months` it fills the array with around 100 of: `array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "2017-12-12" } array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "2017-12-12" } array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "2017-12-12" }`  where it should only show 1 row of  `array(1) { [0]=> string(10) "2017-12-12" }`

Comment: Great approach, lucky you don't have 10 colors/ranges :)

Comment: @Marcodor It's for a calibration DB/Library, so more than 3 colors are not needed ^^

Comment: @KevinHR Is there a way to check for dublicates inside the 3 arrays, on every loop?

Comment: @KevinHR I found a problem in the select statement you provided, i noticed that it didn't provide the`$Row` array with the days remaining, but the dates. I Deleted the `as Days_Remaining` from the select statement and i get the correct values when i `Var_Dump($Row)` so it should fill the arrays as supposed when i find the time to tinker with the < / > values as they get returned as a negative interger (-74 days untill 12-12-2017)

Comment: I am able to populate the 3 arrays with the values that match the array filler calculation. Though it loops in every remaining_day values like this:

1 is correct. 2 has 1 and 2. 3 has 1,2,3. 4 has 1,2,3,4 and so on, you get what i mean i hope
`array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "-74" } --
array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "-74" [1]=> string(3) "-32" } --
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "-74" [1]=> string(3) "-32" [2]=> NULL } --
array(4) { [0]=> string(3) "-74" [1]=> string(3) "-32" [2]=> NULL [3]=> NULL }`

NULL is row 3 and 4 in the database which is currently 0000-00-00 But i'm sure you will cath it.

Answer (score 0):

If *individual date per row* is known at the database level, then use `DATEDIFF` function as Kevin pointed. Also, some other DBMSes (not sure about MySQL) allow simple math between two dates, like `(date1 - date2) as delta_days`.

If you know the date later, on PHP level, then use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) class, diff method. Much simpler and safe to use. It can take a lot of input formats as date and later do the math.

Comment: I have the date difference from what Kevin provided, now i just need to seperate them into 3 array and count the rows in each array :-)

Comment: may use `case` statement in SQL, to separate periods in ranges/colors, or do it in php also using a case. please be more specific in your questions. you started with "calculate days" and ended with "green/red" while echo'ing html table.

Comment: You are misunderstanding, Kevin is leading me the right way, i am almost at the finishing line The red/yellow/green is just to give an example  how the table acts when it gets the number of days left, it has nothing to do with the calculation itself. :-)